# Change default python version in IDLE

Tags: python, default, idle-python

So, I'd like to have Python 2.7.6 when I open the IDLE (that is the one pre-installed on Ubuntu); instead, the idle opens with the one that I have installed (2.7.5). 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you need Python 2 just type `idle` in terminal.

If you need Python3 type `idle3`.

I have both Python2 and Python3 installed and also idle and idle3.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo nano /usr/bin/idle-python2.7`

It looks like this

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

from idlelib.PyShell import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Change the end of the first line to reflect your desire.

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7.6
```

`^X`  to save, and `y` to consent.

Give it a whirl.

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: @StefanoDeRosso, you still have Python 2.7.6 installed, right?

Comment: I have Python 2.7.6 installed, and when I run it from the terminal it is the default one. I've changed it to the default using the "ln" command.
Anyway, I've came through the problem - even though in an "alternative" way -, by uninstalling and reinstalling the IDLE in Ubuntu Software Center.

In any case I'd like to resolve it the other way, too.

Comment: but when you execute `/usr/bin/idle-python2.7`, modified or not, from the command line the idle is 2.7.5?

Comment: hey hey, executing "/usr/bin/idle-python2.7", it works! It opens the IDLE for Python 2.7.6. 
But is there some way to make it happen only writing "idle" on the terminal?

Comment: Sure, the instructions are in `/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib` prepend the parent of this idlelib dir to sys.path.  Otherwise, importing idlelib gets the version installed with the Python used to call this module:`...or un-install 2.7.5

Comment: Ugh, I don't know how, but it seems that there is no "idlelib" directory in Python 2.7.6; there is, instead, this directory in Python 2.7.5

Comment: I don't know, maybe it means something that I have installed the 2.7.6 IDLE from the Software Center and not from the Terminal?
Because its directory is "usr/bin/idle-python2.7"

Comment: `idlelib` is in `2.7.5` *because* that was the version of Python **into which** it was installed.   If you want to call up Idle from the terminal with just `idle` you *must* *either* remove it from 2.7.5, *or* remove 2.7.5 from your system.  It can't be in both.  It wouldn't *know* which way to go. But since you've essentially scabbed on 2.7.6 with a symbolic link either option is not as simple as it sounds.